# ERROR Error: ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges inangularjs

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, angular-changedetection

I have a component customer-management in which i m showing list of customers and on click of view button i m navigating to another component customer-detail where i m displaying in tab. on customer-details component it is showing following error

```
ERROR Error: ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges
    at viewDestroyedError (core.js:20452)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23908)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23307)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:24177)
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (core.js:23879)
    at ViewRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges (core.js:21688)
    at ngx-bootstrap-dropdown.js:639
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:993)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
```

Comment: Can you add your code here or on blitz. Its difficult to understand the problem currently

Answer (score 1):

Typically, this happens when you subscribe to an external Observable inside a component that triggers a change detection. When you don't unsubscribe on destroying of the component, the Observable fires and you try to start change detection on a component that doesn't exist anymore.

Typical example:

```
@Component({...})
class MyComponent {
  Input() myTrigger$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myTrigger$.subscribe(() => {
      // do anything useful...
      this.cdr.detectChanges(); // <- This call fails, once the component is destroyed
    });
  }
}
```

Solution in this example would be to keep the subscription reference and unsubscribe on destroy. **You should not only do this for the change detector, but also to avoid serious memory leaks in general**:

```
@Component({...})
class MyComponent {
  Input() myTrigger$: Observable<any>;
  private sub: Subscription;


  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.myTrigger$.subscribe(() => { // <- keep the subscription for later
      ...
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe(); // <- unsubscribe on destroy
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inested of all these hussles, you can use below method when you want to update UI. This is a better implementation of Change Detection, Hoping this should be mentioned on Angular documentation.

```
detectChanges () {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if ( this.cdRef !== null &&
                this.cdRef !== undefined &&
                ! (this.cdRef as ViewRef).destroyed ) {
                    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
            }

        }, 250);
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks. It works without `setTimeout`.

Comment: Thanks, Aniket. Please vote here if you found it helpful.